# How to get Discount Start and End Date from Commerce Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce, commerce

I am trying to retrieve the start and end date of a discount using Microsoft Commerce Server, server side code. How can this be achieved? The only data I am stuck with is the promo code "TEST". There are not a lot of code samples on how I can just create the Discount object or CampaignItem object and set the promo code to retrieve its properties. Please help.

Comment: You seem to be asking about the start and end date of a discount, but then say you are stuck on getting the promo code properties.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: The goal is the get the discount start and end date properties from Commerce Server but to do that I'm not sure what method I should use to create the objects needed to obtain those properties

Comment: OK.  Are you using Commerce Server 2007 API or Commerce Server 2009?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet demonstrates how to get the `StartDate` and `EndDate` for a Commerce Server `Discount`.  This assumes you are using the Commerce Server 2007 API and that you know the ID of the discount you want the dates from.

```
//The discount id we want to get dates from.
var discountId = 12;//Set to your ID.

//Configure the Commerce Server site name.
var siteName = "StarterSite";

//We need a MarketingContext instance so we can access the marketing API. 
var mc = MarketingContext.Create(siteName, null, AuthorizationMode.NoAuthorization);

//Get our discount.
var discount = (Discount)mc.CampaignItems.GetCampaignItem(discountId);

//Voila.  Start and End dates.
var startDate = discount.StartDate;
var endDate = discount.EndDate;
```

Note:  The `MarketingContext.Create` overload, returns a `MarketingContext` instance that utilises the marketing system management API in *local mode*.  For more information on these modes, see [Understanding the Different Types of Commerce Server APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545714%28v=cs.70%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there a way to grab the Discount by promo code name (ie. TENOFF)? Or does it have it be by discount id?

Comment: You can do this via the API, although it will be quite long winded.  Are you happy to use direct SQL?  If so, you could try the solution here http://microsoftblog.co.in/commerceserver/get-discounts-for-a-given-promotion-code/